# Meaning of "if the shoe fits wear it" doesn't fit

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

Just now I read the phrase's [meaning](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-the-shoe-fits.html) and was surprised.

I always thought that the meaning goes like this: if something is in a really bad or unacceptable condition, but it's serving the purpose, then don't dispose of it, or don't complain unnecessarily about it.

Don't you think the meaning I explained is closer to the phrase?

Comment: A phrase that more closely aligns with your interpretation is "if it ain't broke, don't fix it." :)

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of *[if it ain't broke, don't fix it](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain't_broke,_don't_fix_it)*? I've always understood *if the shoe fits* in the sense given, similar to *if it looks like a duck*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it doesn't have anything to do with the utility still left in an object or imperfect situation.

There is an idiom (or proverb) for a situation in which, when something is in a really bad/unacceptable condition but serviceable, then don't dispose of it.

The phrase is "make do" or, more frugal yet, "Use it up, wear it out, make it do, or do without."

If the shoe fits... originally it came from "if the cap fits...", which alluded to a fool's cap and dates from the early 1700s. It is thought that it changed to *shoe* as a result of the Cinderella tale.

"If the shoe fits, wear it" [means](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_the_shoe_fits), if something has all of the characteristics of a thing, it probably is that thing. More specifically, when *a person* has certain behaviors consistent with [unflattering label], then they should not object because they have been described that way. A person who acts a fool should not object to wearing a fool's cap.

E.g. Imagine person A is always prying into everyone's life, including that of person B. B doesn't like it, and says to A, "I don't like busybodies". A says, "Are you calling me a busybody?" Person B then replies, "If the shoe fits, wear it."

If it describes you, it probably *is* you.

Comment: good explanation the example changed the image of this phrase in my mind

Comment: Not entirely accurate according to this article.  http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-the-shoe-fits.html

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - Kindly explain how so? It gives an additional earlier rendition (cloak), which I omitted, but my answer is entirely accurate, even according to that article. Mind you, I don't take offense at being corrected. Being correctly called out is an opportunity to learn. But omission of an earlier rendition is not the same as being inaccurate.

Comment: Thorough explanation Idiom 1 and Idiom 2.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of "If the shoe fits, wear it" is that if something suits your purpose, use it (for example, in response to someone who suggests another way of doing something that I am doing and I do not think that the other way is better).

Comment: Hello, Mirielle. I suggest you look the proverb up in major reference works on the internet. Your understanding of the phrase seems non-standard. // Answers here should always be more than unsupported opinion.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of this is about life in general. If something in life doesn't work for you then find another fit. We are all not a one size fits all personality. We all have our own characteristics that allow us to fit somewhere where we belong rather than forcing something upon ourselves Tha doesn't feel right

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//english.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Answer (score -1):

It simply means ''dont try so hard'' this phrase orginated from the fairytale of *Cinderella* you may be wondering why. We all saw the happy ending version of Cinderella, the family friendly one but in the actual story cinderella's step sister **cut off their toes**! so that the heal could fit.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the EL&U. Your answer would be even better if your provided reliable sources proving that the information you are giving is correct!

Comment: As mentioned in the OP " In 1634, Giambattista Basile, published Il Pentamerone, a popular collection of Italian folk tales. One of the stories, Cenerentola, is the basis of the Cinderella story as we now know it, complete with wicked stepmother, ugly sisters and a missing slipper."