# Source of "If the shoe fits, buy it in every colour"

Tags: quotes

What is the origin of the following quote:

> If the shoe fits, buy it in every colour

I'm familiar with the phrase '[If the shoe fits...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152677/meaning-of-if-the-shoe-fits-wear-it-doesnt-fit)' and I'm curious as to whether this is a derivative and roughly when it first came into use.

Comment: Have you done any research? [Welcome to the Quote Garden](http://www.quotegarden.com/shopping.html) labels it as 'author unknown'. There aren't too many examples on the internet, and the Google Ngram for "buy it in every colour" shows a flatline. It's probably better regarded as still a catchphrase rather than a new proverb.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the origin of a quote. Asking about the origin of idioms or common phrases would be on topic but not "Who said this?"

Comment: @terdon Sorry if it's off-topic. I'd considered it (admittedly loosely) based on the etymology. I wasn't after who said it, I was more interested in when and how it came to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an amalgam of an old expression: "If the shoe fits, wear it" and a shopping maxim that goes back (at least) to the early 20th century.

**If the shoe fits, wear it**

This article covers  the meaning and history well

> This expression is often used when something derogatory is said about
>   a person who then complains to a third party. The third party, if they
>   agree with the original negative comment, might suggest "If the shoe
>   fits, then wear it". An example of that might be:
>
> Jack: Just because I've missed two or three sessions, my fitness trainer says I lack motivation.
>   Jill: Well, if the shoe fits, wear it.
>   [phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-the-shoe-fits.html)

**Buy it in every color**

This from 1980, "[Some women like a shoe so they buy it in every color](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uHquAAAAIAAJ&q=%22buy%20it%20in%20every%20color%22&dq=%22buy%20it%20in%20every%20color%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBWoVChMIr9yS7_OAyQIVBXkPCh1zZA16)." and this from 1937 "[And they keep returning— buy it in every color](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Hq4iAQAAMAAJ&q=%22buy%20it%20in%20every%20color%22&dq=%22buy%20it%20in%20every%20color%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEAQ6AEwA2oVChMI4_m7xvOAyQIVxIMPCh2rrQSt)."

Both of the above come from a [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22buy%20it%20in%20every%20color%22&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1900%2Ccd_max%3A1990&tbm=bks) for "buy it in every color"

I'll let you continue with your own research now! Try searching Google Books for relevant phrases. You can specify a range of dates in the Search Tools.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'd done some regular searches which had not yielded many results that weren't linked to purchasing a product, but hadn't considered book searches